# python flask base.html doesn't display {{user.username}

Tags: flask

Here is my base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('dashboard') }}">SOM</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

profile.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<h3>{{user.username}}</h3>
```

When I go to the profile page it doesn't display the username but if I type something else there like `<h1> Hello </h1>` I can see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<h3>Hello, {{ user.username }}</h3>
```

and all you see is "Hello", your next step is to verify that you're passing a `user` key to `render_template`, and that the value has a non-blank `username` field.

Then take another look at the [extends](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#template-inheritance) documentation, and note the part about overriding blocks.